# vue component props sync

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My vue component has two props `a` and `b` (`a` for v-model). In the component I need to do some logics when both `a` and `b` changed, actually `a` and `b` will be changed together always. But I don't want to combine them in to one object. If use `watch`, I must handle the changes respective. How do I get the opportunity when both variables changed?

Comment: So, what is your question?. How do you need us to help?

Comment: @Johna How do I get the opportunity when both variables changed?

Comment: You can use b in computed

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html gives you the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use b in computed

I assume that `a` is `firstName` & `lastName`, and `b` is `fullName`.

You can do something like this

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" v-model="firstName">
    <input type="text" v-model="lastName">
    <span>{{ fullName }}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
        }
    },
    computed: {
        fullName () {
            return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default {
  props: ['a', 'b'],
  computed: {
    abHandler () { return {a: this.a, b: this.b } }
  },
  watch: {
    abHandler () {
      console.log('a or b has changed')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it?